# How do I resolve my deployment 'application error' on Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment

Someone suggested Heroku. I connected it to my github. After deploying it tells me application error see below:

"

Application Logs

```
2021-05-13T05:33:11.974735+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-05-13T05:33:17.434161+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-05-13T05:33:21.152639+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! missing script: start
2021-05-13T05:33:21.177166+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-05-13T05:33:21.179883+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-05-13T05:33:21.183465+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-05-13T05_33_21_153Z-debug.log
2021-05-13T05:33:21.253969+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-05-13T05:33:21.354019+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-05-13T05:33:22.611937+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=intelhubdev.herokuapp.com request_id=56993659-8105-4f1a-b1a0-ff53a2c65ae2 fwd="197.210.45.44" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-13T05:33:23.853075+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=intelhubdev.herokuapp.com request_id=fbd4eed8-7477-4de3-b3a2-6438c536c470 fwd="197.210.45.44" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https"
```

Comment: can you attach your `package.json` file

Comment: Its been resolved thanks.